# Allow anonymous users to create unpublished nodes in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system, triggers

I'm creating a site for a client based on drupal, and the client wants an anonymous user (not logged in) to be able to create a new node, but only an unpublished one. Then an admin can review the node and alter it before publishing himself.

I have looked at using triggers and actions, but writing a custom trigger module seems a bit daunting, as I'm not very fluent with the Drupal API currently. Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that without custom coding or triggers/actions.

You could use 2 different node types, one for each group, and then treat them the same when displaying. Alternatively you should be able to, in the "presave" op of nodeapi to publish or unpublish depending on role.

Just set the anonymous users content type's default 'status' to unpublished and set the permissions for the content type to allow anonymous users to create that type of content.

Answer (score 3):

For Drupal 7 you can apply @Mirzu solution this way :

```
function <your-module-name>_node_presave($node) {
    if (user_is_anonymous())
        $node->status = FALSE; // means unpublished
}
```

Of course you can do it the other way round :
Defining the content type to be *unpublished*, and then setting it *published* for authenticated users in the hook.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish that without custom coding or triggers/actions. Just set the content type's default to unpublished and set the permissions for the content type to allow anonymous users to create that type of content.

Comment: That could work... Except then every time an authenticated user (not necessarily an admin) published a node, they would have to make sure and check the published box. That seems a little inconvenient... Can you think of a way to automatically publish nodes by authenticated users?

Comment: In a custom module, you could write an implementation of hook_form_alter to override the default published status for authenticated users.

Comment: You could use 2 different node types, one for each group, and then treat them the same when displaying. Alternatively you should be able to, in the "presave" op of nodeapi to publish or unpublish depending on role.

Comment: Thanks mirzu, I used your second suggestion. I just created a quick module with a hook_nodeapi() implementation. It works great!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks goes to @mirzu. For anyone interested, I used the following code:

```
function hook_nodeapi($node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL)
{
    global $user;
    if( $op == 'presave' && !$user->uid)
    {
        db_query('UPDATE node SET status="0" WHERE nid="' . $node->nid . '"');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your hook_nodeapi() 'presave' rather than:

```
db_query('UPDATE node SET status="0" WHERE nid="' . $node->nid . '"');
```

could you not just use:

```
$node->status = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default publish status to unpublished - and hide that field from anonymous users.

Then you can create a view - or just use the Content link in the admin section to view the pages that have Anonymous for an author, and are unpublished - then you can review nodes from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this hook in drupal 8

```
function MODULENAME_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {

  if( $entity->bundle() == 'BUNDLENAME' && in_array('anonymous', \Drupal::currentUser()->getRoles() ) ) {
    $entity->setPublished(FALSE);
  }

}
```